# Script that checks if a process is running, if it is not running execute line of codes

Tags: linux, bash, process, debian

How can I create a script that checks if a process is running, and when it is not running executes a line of codes? And let the script check every minute?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
case "$(pidof Program.exe | wc -w)" in
0)  echo "Restarting Program: $(date)" >> /var/log/ProgramLog.txt
(mono-runtime Program.exe -option1 yes -option2 no -option3 6; 1) &
;;
1)  # all ok
;;
*)  echo "Removed double Program: $(date)" >> /var/log/ProgramLog.txt
kill $(pidof Program.exe | awk '{print $1}')
;;
esac
```

0: If no process is found execute the code

1: If process is found do nothing

*: If there is more than 1 process found stop the last one

there are 2 codes to execute:

mono-runtime Program.exe -option1 yes -option2 no -option3 6

and behind the semicolon: 1

Is this a correct way to do that?:
(mono-runtime Program.exe -option1 yes -option2 no -option3 6; 1) &

Comment: I would rather suggest some lock mechanism, e.g. opening a socket, creating a private MMAP, locking a specific temp file etc, from within program.exe. if that lock acquire fails, then exit without doing anything. & in your bash script, just trigger a new launch of the process.

Comment: @anishsane This is to make it more carefully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monit (small software) will do all this job for you:

Please look here:

```
https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/
```

Comment: Yes this seems an option, I figured I could also use Crontab to time the checks.

Comment: You don't need a cron then. Monit works as a demon which checks if process is running, if not monit restarts it, so it helps you to keep process up all time.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you're trying to make sure there's always one instance of your program running on the machine. Have you considered adding this program to `/etc/inittab`? With this file you can configure your init system to run the program for you and restart whenever it exits (crashes).
Some more information: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?inittab+5